# Count unique values (factors) in a data.frame and return a summary

Tags: r, dplyr, count, summarize

I have looked everywhere here in SO and did not find a solution.

I am trying to create a summary of unique values (factors) of my data set.

Consider this data:

```
df <- structure(list(x = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, NA, NA), .Label = c("A", 
"H", "M", "R", "Z"), class = "factor"), y = structure(c(NA, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("H", "I", "K", "T", "W"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

I am trying to achieve something like this (list, df, tibble are all welcome):

```
df_sum <- data.frame(A = 1, H = 2, I = 1, M = 1, R = 1, Z = 1,
                 K = 1, T = 1)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are the K and T and W excluded from the output?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Forgot to add them (doing it manually). Thanks, @JonSpring.

Comment: `table(unlist(df))`? If you want to count  `NA`s as well use `table(unlist(df), useNA = "ifany")`

Comment: That's perfect, @Roman! Thank you very much! Could you please add it as an answer?

Comment: it's surely a duplicate.